# vendor autoload file cannot be loaded because of the public folder in codeigniter 4

Tags: composer-php, codeigniter-4

I already installed GuzzleHttp using composer but the `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` returns an error. I've tried `using FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';` and it returns C:\xampp\htdocs\local\public\vendor\autoload.php". I think the problem is the public folder in the url. When I tried it without the public folder it works.

Comment: "returns an error." - what does that mean? Can you share the full and exact error message, along with the code you are using?

Comment: Seems more like htaccess issue.

Comment: I solved the path issue using this code `require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 0):

#### Notes:

[`FCPATH`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=fcpath#FCPATH)

> The path to the directory that holds the front controller.

[`ROOTPATH`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=fcpath#ROOTPATH)

> The path to the project root directory. Just above [`APPPATH`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=fcpath#APPPATH).

##### Solution:

Instead of:❌

```php
require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Use this:✅

```php
require_once ROOTPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

---

You could alternatively, use `COMPOSER_PATH`:✅

I.e:

```php
require_once COMPOSER_PATH;
```

> [Composer Path](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/43fae6293b5efcc31d34b54a0ef1a50847e0e1ee/app/Config/Constants.php#L20)

> The path that Composer's autoload file is expected to
> live. By default, the vendor folder is in the Root directory, but you
> can customize that here.